# How to make WPF Datagrid Column non-focusable?

Tags: wpf, focus, wpfdatagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have a WPF `DataGrid` being used for data entry but some `DataGridTextColumn` are information only and I have set their `IsReadOnly="True"` so their cells do not go into edit mode. However, they can still receive focus which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

Use a cell style and set Focusable=False.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" 
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

    ....
```